# Strongly connected component

Tags: java, graph

Given total number of V vertices and total number of E edges of a graph G, how can I compute largest strongly connected component with minimum number of vertices & edges in strongly connected component of graph.

Eg. for graph with 5 vertices and 7 edges, the minimum size of connected component is 3. 
This graph can be modeled so that there are more connected components but minimum is 3.

The problem I am facing is that edge information is not given to me. Only the total number of edges are given. I wanted to use [Tarjan's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) algorithm using depth first search but I need edge information.

Is it possible to find the size of strongly connected component with minimum vertices and edges just total number of vertices and total number of edges.

Comment: You should probably specify a language. Otherwise, consider the CS SE site.

Comment: Java is the language I want to use but not sure that matters.

Comment: You should try adding the Java tag, then.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way I can think of is to consider trying to utilise the edges to form components that are [Complete Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) of size 1, then 2, etc until you find one that works.

A complete graph of size n has (n<sup>2</sup> - n) / 2 edges. So to split into components of size n will look something like

```
numFullComponents := V/n //integer division
numEdgesUsed := numFullComponents * n * (n-1) / 2 //This is edges from full components
    + (V%n) * (V%n - 1)/2 //a complete graph on the remainder nodes
```

You can then compare that number of edges used with the number of edges in the graph. The smallest n that uses at least E edges is the solution.

Comment: I suspect that there is also an O(1) solution, but I'm not going to try to work that out.